# Paginacion en PHP pasar parametros

Tags: php, mysql

He estado intentando hacer mi primera paginación en php, pero me tope con el problema de que no estoy utilizando algo llamado PDO para la conexión y necesito pasar al `LIMIT` de la base de datos los parámetros, y tienen que estar en enteros si no me equivoco.

El problema esta en que necesito usar un código para convertir un array a enteros y la función bindPraram no me funciona, hay alguna manera de hacerlo sin este parámetro?

```
//iniciador en la base de datos
$iniciar = ($_GET['pagina'] - 1) * $ordenes_x_pagina;

//limitar las ordenes en la base de datos y pasar parametro
$ordenes2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ordenes LIMIT :iniciar,:nordenes");

//convertir a enteros
$ordenes2->bindParam(':iniciar', $iniciar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ordenes2->bindParam(':nordenes', $ordenes_x_pagina, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Encontre algo pero tampoco pude hacerlo funcionar pero creo q estoy mas cerca:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ordenes LIMIT (?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss', $iniciar, $ordenes_x_pagina);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Por lo cual tengo otra duda adicional; ¿Qué es mejor, usar `pdo` en la conexión o usar `new msqli`?

Código completo solo me faltaría agregar el código para mostrar el ciclo while y for con el limite de 5 en cada click por igual (aquí se me quemo la cabeza)

```
<body>


<?php require_once('conexion.php');

$ordenes = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ordenes");

$ordenes_x_pagina = 5;
//contar ordenes de nuestra base
$resultado = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM ordenes");
$filadeordenes = $resultado->fetch_array();
$total_ordenes_db = $filadeordenes["Total"];
// echo $total_ordenes_db;
$paginas = $total_ordenes_db / 5;
// redondeamos el numero de paginas
$paginas = ceil($paginas);
// echo $paginas;

// obligar a que la pagina tenga la primera paginacion al entrar
if (!$_GET){
    header('Location:index.php?pagina=1');
}
// redireccionar si un valor mal introducido
if($_GET['pagina']>$paginas || $_GET['pagina'] <= 0){
    header('Location:index.php?pagina=1');
}

// limitador dinamico
$iniciar = ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$ordenes_x_pagina;

//limitar entradas a 5 por paginacion
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ordenes LIMIT ?,?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $iniciar, $ordenes_x_pagina);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$resultado_limite = $stmt->fetch_array();

echo "<h1>Total de ordenes</h1>";
echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
echo "<tr><th>ID Orden</th>";
echo "<th >ID Cliente</th>";
echo "<th '>Fecha de la orden</th>";
echo "<th >Fecha de envió</th>";
echo "<th >Total</th>";
while ($fila = $ordenes->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($columna = 0; $columna < 5; $columna++) {
        echo "<td>$fila[$columna]</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table> <br>";


?>    

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina'] ==$i+1 ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
            <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina'] - 1 ?>">
                Anterior
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $paginas; $i++) : ?>
            <li class="page-item <?php
                                    echo $_GET['pagina'] == $i + 1 ? 'active' : ''  ?>">
                <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $i + 1; ?>">
                    <?php echo $i + 1; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endfor ?>
        <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina'] >= $paginas ? 'disabled' : '' ?> ">
            <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina'] + 1 ?>">
                Siguiente
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: El `LIMIT` es donde le indicas a la consulta la cantidad de filas que va a traer como resultado: `SELECT * FROM ordenes LIMIT 1` por ejemplo. Que quieres lograr con esa consulta?

Comment: Hay quiero hacerlo dinámico, para lograr la paginación de 5 en 5,

Comment: En `LIMIT (?,?)` los paréntesis sobran.

Comment: @Sal Gracias, funciono, sabes ahora como pasárselo al while como arreglo?